# Redux-form async validation, avoid using "throw"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

So i am using redux-form and following the example for async validation in documentation, everything is working fine but i want to avoid using throw to throw object like below

```
throw {email:"Already exists"}
```

I have tried using "SubmissionError" but when i throw SubmissionError, it adds and object called "errors" inside "asyncErrors" in redux and then errors are not displayed below field, they are displyed if i just throw it like this     throw {email:"Already exists"}
Below is my code using SubmissionError

```
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { doesUserExist } from '../../shared/endpoints/userEndpoint';

const asyncValidate = (values /*, dispatch */) => {
  return doesUserExist(values.get('email')).then((res) => {
    if (res.registered) {
      throw new SubmissionError({ email: 'This email is already in use.' });
    }
  });
};

export default asyncValidate;
```

output redux state is -

```
form: {
registerForm:{
 asyncErrors:{
  errors:{email: "This email is already in use."}
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the actual output that you are getting after throwing `SubmissionError`?

Comment: i have added the output

Comment: Are you getting this output after you throw `SubmissionError`? Where is the string `Already Exists` in your code?

Comment: sorry, i have changed the output

Answer (score 2):

The `SubmissionError` in redux forms will add general errors in `asyncErrors` object as it is given in the docs.

> If it is rejected with a redux-form SubmissionError containing errors in the form { field1: 'error', field2: 'error' } then the submission errors will be added to each field (to the error prop) just like async validation errors are.

Refer [here](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/docs/api/reduxform.md/#:%7E:text=then%20the%20submission%20errors%20will%20be%20added%20to%20each%20field%20(to%20the%20error%20prop)%20just%20like%20async%20validation%20errors%20are)